# How to refresh UI data after filling a dataset through OleDbAdapter?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-core, data-binding, oledb

I have a simple WPF VB.Net application connecting to an Access database.
I am querying the database to fill my textboxes on a window with customer data, so that i can edit, insert and delete it.
The textboxes are inside a grid and i bound them to each column of the datatable inside the dataset i get from the OleDbAdapter.
I bound the Grid.DataContext to the dataset's table.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Cli WHERE Cod = " & txtCod.Text & ";"
anaDA.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, conndb)
anaDA.Fill(anaDS, "Ana")
AnaGrid.DataContext = anaDS.Tables("Ana")
```

The first time i type the customer index and run this code it works.
If i run anaDS.Tables("Ana").Clear and redo the search, my UI doesn't get refreshed (the datatable is getting filled with correct data if i pause and check during runtime).
I read online i need to notify the UI that data has changed inside the dataset to refresh textboxes, but how do i do it?
Maybe i am missing something but, shouldn't there be an easy way to do it after a datatable gets filled?
I'm losing my mind reading everywhere on google.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the record, you don't get a `DataSet` from a data adapter. The data adapter gets the `DataSet` from you.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use WPF like WinForms but it's not really made to work that way. Ideally, you should have a view model that exposes the `DataTable` via a property and you would then bind that property to the UI. The view model would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you would raise the appropriate event to notify the UI that the data had changed. I'm not a WPF expert but I think that, in your case, the only option is to set the `DataContext` to `Nothing` and then bind it again.

Comment: Setting DataContext to Nothing and binding it again does not work sadly

Comment: Well, anyways, if i'm not using WPF correctly i'd better check out how to use a view model. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You should look into the MVVM (model-view-viewmodel) design pattern. It's basically how WPF is done. The model is the data, the view is the window and the view model is an object that brokers between the two, exposing the specific data and behaviour required for a specific view.

Comment: Did you try `AnaGrid.ItemsSource= anaDS.Tables("Ana").DefaultView`?

Comment: It's a normal Grid not DataGrid. I have multiple textboxes inside that i wanted to populate with database columns.